# как решить проблему с картинкой она разьезжается

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

верстка на bootstrap3

```css
.order-block{
  background: black;
}

.info-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 315px;
  height: 638px;
  top: 0;
  left: 73px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXdo7.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="order-block">
  <div class="info-block">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <div class="info-block"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"> <span class="phone">+7 (910) 216-78-93</span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Фон с вырезам для кнопки][image: Дизайн]

Comment: Добавьте код html, чтобы было возможно воспроизвести вашу ошибку/проблему здесь

Comment: <div class="order-block">
    <div class="info-block">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="info-block">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <span class="phone">+7 (910) 216-78-93</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Андрей, если вы хотите чтоб вам помогли - добавьте код который у вас уже есть html и css, применив кнопку править.

Answer (score 0):

Вы два раза используете `.info-block` для разных по ширине контейнеров `div`.

```
<div class="order-block">
  <div class="info-block">
    ...
       <div class="info-block"></div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

По этому получается такой эффект. Удалите один класс.

Comment: СПС!, не заметил